# How start multiple rails app servers with a ruby script

Tags: ruby, shell, scripting, rvm, foreman

I'm writing a ruby script to start more than one rails server, but I'm running into a few problems:

1. When I programmatically `cd` into different projects, their respective `.rvmrc` files aren't triggered. My projects all use different versions of ruby and have unique gemsets, so I need my script to recognize which environment it's in for everything to work correctly. I tried changing gemsets programmatically, but received this error from rvm:

   `RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.`
2. I'm using foreman to start each app, which is great for distilling more than one startup command into a nice and simple `foreman start -p $PORT`, but I would also like each app's logs to be displayed in their own terminal window, or even better, their own tab. I've seen others achieve things like this through applescript, but is there a better way?

Comment: Not sure how your script looks like, but this might help you:
https://rvm.io/workflow/scripting/

Comment: [This post on childprocess](http://www.mikeperham.com/2012/12/07/12-gems-of-christmas-6-childprocess/) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. I ended up using [consular](https://github.com/achiu/consular), which handles scripting in a way that respects different `.rvmrc` files. Please see [this post](http://boredbusiness.tumblr.com/post/47686449581) for more information on my specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

It should be simple as:

```
rvm . do foreman start -p $PORT
```